# Error installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I know other people have asked this but the suggested fixes don't seem to work for me.  I'm trying to install Rails v. 3.2.3 on a Mac OS X Lion, using Ruby 1.8.7.  In terminal:

```
$ sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.3
```

And then I get the error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

I've seen some people suggest installing Xcode v. 4.3.2, which I have, but I'm not sure if I need to do something special with Xcode to get the Rails installation to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read the linked comment in this URL:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/191688#1055352

Answer (score 1):

The easiest install way is by using RVM 
here is a pretty good guide:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ruby-on-rails/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion/

Comment: Thanks.  I used the suggestion in the link deniatus, but thanks for the resource.